# Detecting deploy failure from Ansistrano Deploy

Tags: deployment, ansible

We are using [Ansistrano Deploy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ansistrano/deploy)

```yaml
roles:
  - role: ansistrano.deploy
```

We want to be able to detect when the deploy fails for any reason (or succeeds), so we can send a Slack notification.

How can we get a return code or similar on this to know the result of the deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not being familiar under the hood with Ansistrano and more specifically with the error handling already in place inside the role, I'm not entirely sure this will work out of the box.

But my first natural attempt would be to use a [block with error handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks). This will require to change the way you call the role to use [`import_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html) instead of the play-level `role:` keyword.

Here is a pseudo playbook example to give you the global idea:

```yaml
- hosts: my_deploy_hosts
  
  tasks:
    - name: deploy my_app with some error control
      block:
        - name: run the ansistrano deploy role
          import_role:
            name: ansistrano.deploy

        - name: If we got there, above ran successfully
          debug:
            msg: "You should send a ++ message to slack"

      rescue:
        - name: If we get into this something went wrong
          debug:
            msg: "Houston. Houston. We have a problem."
```